# Як правильно писати назви електронних валют: e-voucher чи e-Voucher, wex rur чи Wex RUR?

Tags: орфографія

Роз'ясніть, будь ласка, як правильно писати назви електронних валют. Чи є сталі нормативи щодо їх написання? На різних сайтах спостерігаю різні варіанти. В словниках дуже складно знайти обгрунтування правильного написання.

Answer (score 2):

**Написання іноземних назв (власних чи загальних) не регулюється правилами української мови.**

Якби ці назви були транслітеровані на кирилицю чи ще якимось способом адаптовані до української мови (тобто вони вже не були б оригінальними іноземними назвами), то можна було б говорити про традиції/правила, що застосовуються при адапації на українську мову (чи дотримані вони в певному випадку, який варіант адаптації для певного слова кращий і т. ін.). Але у Вашому випадку це суто іноземні (неадаптовані) назви.

Answer (score 0):

В словники ще не включили нормативне написання поданих іноземних слів.

1. Е-voucher — це електронний банківський чек, спеціальний код Perfect Money, електронної платіжної системи. Використовується для безготівкових розрахунків в Інтернеті. На офіційному сайті Perfect Money подається таке написання: *e-Voucher* — яке вживається найчастіше.

   Якщо визначати правопис слова за правилами написання скорочених загальних назв (повна — *електронний ваучер*), писати потрібно *e-voucher*, за винятком випадків, коли слово починає речення. Порівняйте: *e-mail* (електронна пошта).
2. WEX RUB. WEX (BTC-e) — платформа для обміну криптовалют. На офіційному сайті WEX написання назви біржі — *WEX*. Літерний код російського рубля дає Вікіпедія — у [переліку валют](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82_(ISO_4217)#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2) російська грошова одиниця позначається як *RUB*.
   Відповідно, правильне написання: *WEX RUB*.

Comment: Поясніть, будь ласка, що це було: це спроба самостійно відповісти на власне запитання? Але чому Ви вирішили, що написання цих слів (і тим більше обирання правильного коду рубля) має якийсь стосунок до української мови?

Comment: Дякую за увагу. Так, я подала правильну і точну відповідь на запитання, доповнила інформацію попередника. Під час написання різноманітних статей я побачила помилкові написання слів іноземного походження. Це стосується мови, на мій погляд. Якщо допускаються помилки у написанні, дати точне написання слів необхідно.

Comment: Я трішки відформатував Вашу відповідь, щоб її легше було читати/зрозуміти. І прибрав слова подяки — тут це не прийнято. Але зважайте, що такі доволі далекі від мови теми не завжди можуть знайти позитивний відгук на цьому сайті.

Comment: Так і не зрозумів, до чого тут українська мова?